# L5: Call to a member function function() on a non-object

Tags: php, laravel

Got a resourceful controller with a `__contruct` function to declare `$project`

```
 public function __construct(Project $project){

    $this->project = $project;
}
```

Then I have an `update` and a `destroy` function which gives an 
`Call to a member function delete() on a non-object` (or `update()` error)

```
 public function edit($id)
{
    $project = $this->project->find($id);
    return view('project.edit', ['project' => $project, 'id' => 'edit']);
}


public function update(CreateProjectRequest $request, $project)
{
    $project->fill($request->input())->save();

    return redirect('project/index');
}


public function destroy($project)
{
    $project->delete();
    return redirect('project');
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: why are you doing this `return $project;` in constructor?

Comment: I actually just noticed I had a return $project there, I deleted it now but it doesn't fix the problem

Answer (score 4):

`$project` in this case is just the id of the project. You have to load it first:

```
public function destroy($projectId)
{
    $project = $this->project->findOrFail($projectId);
    $project->delete();
    return redirect('project');
}
```

Or just use the `destroy` method which takes the key as parameter:

```
public function destroy($projectId)
{
    $this->project->destroy($projectId);
    return redirect('project');
}
```

---

You might also want to look into [Route Model Binding](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/routing#route-model-binding) to fetch the model automatically from the DB.